# BizTalk File Archive Pipeline Component

Tags: biztalk

I was thinking about a pipeline component that could archive the message to the file system, instead of relying on an additional send port.  The advantage would be less subscription and messagebox activity.  I've looked at existing components that do this and they all seem to just write the stream to disk, then re-position and allow the next component to use the stream.  That assumes the stream is seekable.  Some don't even check to see if the stream is seekable.  To make a seekable stream would require some caching mechanism in memory or disk, like how the ReadOnlySeekableStream works if I recall, which incurs more disk activity.

I was thinking about an implementation where you create an "ArchiverStream" that wraps an input stream.  The archiver stream behaves like any other stream, but on read of the archive stream it reads the source stream then writes to the archive the buffer that was read, then allow the reader to continue using the buffer.  Looking for critique on this idea.  Is coupling the archiving logic (write to file) to the reading of the stream a bad idea?  You'd only get a partial archive if only part of the stream was read.  And you'd need logic to handle repositioning of the stream by downstream components.  Is it worth it?

```
public class ArchiverStream : Stream, IDisposable
{
    private Stream _source;
    private string _path;

    private Stream _archive;
    private bool _errorWritingToArchive;

    public ArchiverStream(Stream source, string archivePath)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source), "Source stream is null.");
        }
        _source = source;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(archivePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(archivePath), "Archive path is null or empty.");
        }
        _path = archivePath;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return _source.CanRead;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get
        {
            return _source.CanSeek;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return _source.CanWrite;
        }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _source.Length;
        }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _source.Position;
        }

        set
        {
            _source.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _source.Flush();
    }

    private Stream CreateArchiveStream()
    {

        _archive = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 512, FileOptions.None);
        return _archive;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Read from the source stream,  write the data we read to the archive, and pass the buffer to the caller.  This read will only archive as the stream is read
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer"></param>
    /// <param name="offset"></param>
    /// <param name="count"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var read = _source.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        //If we read some data from the source stream, and we haven't had prior errors writing to the archive.
        if (read > 0 && !_errorWritingToArchive)
        {
            try
            {
                //If we don't have a file open yet, open/create it
                if (_archive == null)
                {
                    _archive = CreateArchiveStream();
                }
                //write contents of buffer
                _archive.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //if we encounter an error writing to archive, don't keep trying on each successive read
                _errorWritingToArchive = true;

                //TODO:raise an event that can be consumed in the pipeline component so we can enable logging of archive issues
            }
        }
        return read;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _source.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _source.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _source.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    private bool _isDisposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="IDisposeable.Dispose()"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// It will call <see cref="Close()"/>
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (disposing && !_isDisposed)
            {
                Cleanup();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Utility method called by the Finalize(), Close() or Dispose() to close and release
    /// both the source and the persistence stream.
    /// </summary>
    private void Cleanup()
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _isDisposed = true;
            if (_archive != null)
            {      
                _archive.Close();
                _archive = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels more like a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question as you haven't clearly identified an issue or problem you are having.  Of course as there isn't even a biztalk tag there, probably not much change of getting an answer there.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - yea,  I checked for atag on codereview and didn't see one.  I basically just wanted a sanity check on my idea.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations

1. You throw an exception if the Archive path is NULL.  Do you really want your interface to fail if you can't archive the file?   Yes, worth logging as an error, but not throwing it out to BizTalk as an error as that will stop the message being processed.
2. My preference is to fully archive to file before any other processing steps are done.  As a failure at another point would cause the archive to fail, and as you say you may not have full file including the part that caused the failure, nor can you reprocess it.  I know this sounds slightly contrary to the above, but I don't want to create any dependency between archiving and processing. I usually have the Archive Pipeline Component as the first one to execute.
3. Regarding Seekable streams, I'd have to do a bit of digging, but apart from rewinding the stream back to 0 after reading it in the Archive component, I usually don't change the position except by reading.